# Idiom for showing off in front of a master

Tags: idioms

What would be an applicable idiom for someone showing off in front of a master? I recently came across the Chinese idiom to "show off one's skill with the axe before Lu Ban" (with Lu Ban being a famous Chinese carpenter) and was struggling to find a comparable idiom in English.

**Edit:** To clarify, I am looking for an idiom where the presence of the master is unknown to the person showing off and possibly humiliating to that person if discovered.

Comment: Do they know they are showing off in front of the master?  E.g. maybe trying to impress the master?  Or are they showing off to someone else and are unaware the master is watching?

Comment: @Jim Edited the post to clarify that point

Comment: @Laurel Thanks for the link! That's definitely very close to what I'm looking for, but I was hoping for something without the teaching element (just showing off/bragging) if that idiom exists.

Comment: There is [_go through one's paces_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20through%20one%27s%20paces) for showing your skills in front of a master which might fit. However, [_put through one's paces_](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/put-through-ones-paces) is more common where the master tests their skills.

Comment: The whole shame/embarrassment thing does not work in the West, as it were.

Comment: @Lambie Another valid point regarding the intractability of the question (as it has been edited. I don't have access to the original.)

Comment: @WillS Is this something you read in Cantonese or Mandarin and translated to English?

Comment: Maybe something with *flaunt*.

Answer (score 0):

**grandstand** or  **showboat**

**grandstand** (v.)

> To play or act so as to impress onlookers [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grandstand)

> (intransitive) To behave dramatically or showily to impress an
> audience or observers; to pander to a crowd.
>
> *Many politicians prefer to grandstand on hot-button issues rather than enact tough policy changes.* [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grandstand)

**showboat** (v.)

> To behave in a conspicuous or ostentatious manner: SHOW OFF [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/showboat)
>
> *Fingers a-flutter, Marsalis confidently flew through composer Jacques Ibert’s flamboyant solo section — making sure his virtuosity was that
> of musicianship, not showboating.*

---

> Leave **grandstanding** and showy display to others. Rather, just do
> the best job you can. By devoting yourself to the work at hand and by
> not drawing attention to yourself, you can develop your talents
> naturally and without interference. [J. Balkin; *The Laws of
> Change*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Laws_of_Change/9RURAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=grandstanding%20with%20showy&dq=grandstanding%20with%20showy&printsec=frontcover) (2002)

> “You were **grandstanding**. Trying to impress everyone with how
> omnipotent you were. And it cost you. . . . Worse yet, it cost *us*.
> [William  Dietz; *Hitman*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hitman_Enemy_Within/8u02GcpL_nAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=was%20grandstanding%20to%20impress&pg=PA39&printsec=frontcover) (2007)

> Of course, I cannot say plainly, 'I don't want to engage in that heavy
> political talk where everyone is **grandstanding**, just trying to
> impress other people and gain points before the Holy Father.'” [Cindy
> Wooden; *Louis Antonio Tagle*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Luis_Antonio_Tagle/S-yeCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=was%20grandstanding%20to%20impress&pg=PT48&printsec=frontcover) (2015)

> Otherwise, he'd never have **showboated** such a flagrant display of
> disdain for his partner's lack of urgency in getting made up for the
> night. [Barry Schnell; *Life in Death*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Life_in_Dearth/kHdpDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22showboated%22%20display&pg=PT214&printsec=frontcover) (2016)

> That game she played selfish basketball, **showboating** for her
> friends. Though all her tricks—behind-the-back passes, crossovers,
> no-look passes, beyond-the-arc shots—were working that day, after a
> quarter I'd seen enough. [B. Resler and C McNerthney; *The Heart of
> the Team*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Heart_of_the_Team/PDBPBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22showboating%22%20for&pg=PT60&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

Answer (score 0):

We have an expression: *to strut your stuff*. It means to show off one’s ability:

> **strut**, *v.<sup>1</sup>*
>
> **f.** ***to strut one’s stuff***: to display one’s ability. *U.S. slang*.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

> *They strutted their stuff in front of Lu Ban.*

Edit: I see your edit might have changed what I was aiming for. Back soon.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, in martial arts, you would **display your skills**.

[display your skills](https://www.google.com/search?q=karate%20master%20%2B%20%22display%20your%20skills%22&ei=yrTdYdSNC-Ok_Qan3b3wDQ&ved=0ahUKEwjUmoi_k6r1AhVjUt8KHaduD94Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=karate%20master%20%2B%20%22display%20your%20skills%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BQghEKABOgQIIRAKOgUIIRCrAkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFAAWMRqYPNsaAJwAngAgAFjiAH8DJIBAjI2mAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)

Answer (score 0):

"Tilting the duck," is the idiom that's used in low lying parts of New Jersey for a hunter who's blasting away at seagulls while veteran hunters are watching from a duck blind.

Comment: I knew there were many reasons for my disliking parts of NJ but this one takes the cake. How truly disgusting.

Answer (score -2):

Shadowboxing: "to box with an imaginary opponent especially as a form of training" M-W. Although shadowboxing's intent is not to show off, it is still demonstrating skills without an audience, which is your context. For example: "The master entered the room where Da was shadowboxing, but stepped back into darkness to admire his pupil's skills."

Or is what the OP is seeking more of a proverb than idiom? (An idiom is a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words, e.g., rain cats and dogs, see the light). "Show off one's skill with the axe before Lu Ban"(what is not deducible from that sentence?)reads like a proverb, but the proverb would only carry the sense the OP seems to be looking for if Lu Ban is a worthless judge. So, "Singing for the ears of a deaf man."

Comment: I believe Lu Ban is a *real* master carpenter, the guy showing off is making himself out to be more than he is to people he thinks don’t know enough to know the difference, but Lu Ban *is* watching the whole show.

Comment: @Jim But "before" indicates that's the master is viewing. Your scenario is logical if the "one" showing off doesn't know the master is there. That's the (unappreciated) point I'm trying to make above. It's not idiom but proverb, and the proverb reads the opposite of the idiom (proverb) the op is seeking. It's conceivable that a context could exist that would invert the given idiom's/proverb's meaning: the master wears a shield of invisibility. Equally important would be the POV. Is the axe-man making the observation (contained in the desired idiom/proverb) or the master? A third party?

Comment: OP says in clarification “where the presence of the master is unknown to the person showing off …”

Comment: @Jim If you've read the above, you must know I understand what the op desires, but the given idiom (proverb) is not one that equates to what the op wants in English. The master who edited the question should have deleted, modified or replaced the given idiom (proverb).

Comment: My understanding is that this is a literal translation of a Chinese proverb that *does* (in Chinese) mean exactly what OP wants. OP understands that the literal translation does not work here and asks for one that does.  OP is *not* looking for something where Lu Ban is a worthless judge. “Singing for the ears of a deaf man” absolutely does not meet OP’s intent.

Comment: @Jim The idiom is  班门弄斧 (Ban Men Nong Fu) Direct Translation: To wield an axe before Lu Ban’s door. "Door!" Before Lu Ban and Before Lu Ban's door are very different things and explains why the axe-wielder (wood crafting) might think he is not being observed (the door is closed).